# What are the performance implications of using multiple threads versus single-threaded

Tags: python

What are the performance implications of using multiple threads versus single-threaded asynchronous programming in Python 3.9?

I've been working with Python for quite a while and I'm familiar with both multi-threading and asynchronous programming (async/await). Recently, I've been optimizing a network-bound application that makes numerous HTTP requests. After a thorough search online, I found conflicting opinions and resources about the performance implications of using multiple threads versus single-threaded asynchronous programming.

From what I've gathered, the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) in Python can limit the effectiveness of multi-threading, especially for CPU-bound tasks. However, my application is IO-bound (specifically network-bound), not CPU-bound. Some articles suggested that multi-threading can still offer benefits in these cases, while others suggested that single-threaded asynchronous programming would be more efficient due to lower overhead.

For the asynchronous programming approach, I've been looking at using asyncio, which is included in the Python standard library, but I've also seen other libraries such as gevent mentioned. I'm unsure of the trade-offs between these options.

So, my specific questions are:

1. In the context of a network-bound Python application, what are the
   performance implications of using multi-threading versus
   asynchronous programming?
2. Are there any major trade-offs or considerations between using
   asyncio and other asynchronous libraries like gevent?

Any insights from those who have practical experience with Python network-bound applications, or authoritative references that can provide a comprehensive comparison would be greatly appreciated.

I believe this question could be relevant to many Python developers who are dealing with IO-bound tasks and are uncertain about which concurrency model could provide the best performance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Python developers who are dealing with IO-bound tasks and are uncertain about which concurrency model could provide the best performance" Those hypothetical Python developers should profile their code rather than relying on generalised advice from the Internet.

Comment: @JonasH Do you have any reason to think Python isn't a good language for that use case?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Are you saying they should slog through the difficultly of implementing a multi-threaded application (maybe even gettng it right) and also write an asyncio version so they can determine which to use?

Answer (score 2):

> However, my application is IO-bound (specifically network-bound), not CPU-bound. Some articles suggested that multi-threading can still offer benefits in these cases, while others suggested that single-threaded asynchronous programming would be more efficient due to lower overhead.

This is correct at a high level.  Both multi-threading and asyncio can be used to improve the performance of IO-bound applications.

> In the context of a network-bound Python application, what are the performance implications of using multi-threading versus asynchronous programming?

Threads have overhead associated with them.  For given application, load, and system that it's executing on, there's some theoretical optimal number of threads.  The number physical processors available is one important factor. I've only skimmed [this article](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/why-too-many-threads-hurts-performance-and-what-to-do-about-it/) but it seems to cover basic concepts.

The big idea of asyncio is that because waiting for IO doesn't involve any computation, you can have the current thread do other things (such as initiate more IO requests) and resume after the IO wait is complete.  In a nutshell, instead of having a bunch of sleeping threads using up system resources and incurring the cost of [thread context switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440128/thread-context-switch-vs-process-context-switch), you can support concurrent IO within a single thread.

> Are there any major trade-offs or considerations between using asyncio and other asynchronous libraries like gevent?

There are tradeoffs but I would tend to prefer asyncio if it is applicable.  Most of the negatives are with the multi-threading approach, especially in Python.

The biggest advantage of asyncio is that it's a simpler concurrency model.  You don't have to work around the GIL which eliminates a lot of nasty multi-threaded failure modes related to thread cache synchronization and locking.  This isn't to say it's *simple*, exactly, just that it can be simpler to get right in a lot of scenarios.  Python also has weak support for multi-threading and it's not something many Python developers are familiar with.  I should note that better support for [multi-threading is coming](https://betterprogramming.pub/real-multithreading-is-coming-to-python-learn-how-you-can-use-it-now-90dd7fb81bdf) but it's going to be a while before it's mainstream.

The main downside of asyncio in Python, in my opinion is that the way is works is obscured by the keywords and interfaces.  You can get into trouble if you don't have a really good mental model of how it actually works.  That is also true for threads (perhaps moreso,) but I think it's easier to mistakenly believe that asyncio is more straightforward than it really is.  The other thing to realize is that, just as with threads, there are limits to how much you can do in a single IO loop.  The main thing to realize is that when IO completes, your thread will not immediately process it.  If you've sent out a ton of IO requests, you can only handle the responses one-at-a-time and that may cause additional delays as each response 'waits its turn' to be handled.  While you may have an IO-bound app, there will be some level of CPU required to process the requests and responses.  If that overhead can vary greatly, that can cause unstable performance.

I would probably start with asynico for an IO-bound process.   My personal experience is that Python is perfectly adequate for such work when using asyncio.  As noted in the comments, you'll want to do a good bit of performance analysis to not only find out how much you can handle per-thread/process but also to determine if asyncio is aqequate and effective for your use-case.

Comment: I would add the thread programming also tends to complicate programming by forcing you to violate encapsulation.  All of a sudden you have to know if the implementation of all functions and methods used are thread safe or not.

Comment: @dietbuddha Agreed.  I've found it difficult to find good documentation and guidance on how to answer that specific question in Python as opposed to say Java. BTW, a pointer to a good reference on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that Python does not have an explicit memory model. Informally, it is clear that accessing variables/dict entries/simple object fields is atomic, and that all changes to Python objects are immediately visible to all threads (think C's seq_cst memory order). This is too limited to be useful in practice – all shared data should be protected by mutexes. Async allows for a much simpler mental model because the control flow won't be interrupted unless I `await` another operation. Downside is that sync + async code doesn't mix, sync stuff must run on background threads.

Comment: @amon I wonder if a more explicit memory model is in the works with the changes that are coming.   Multi-threading without a clear memory model is daunting.

Comment: @JimmyJames PEP 703 which suggests removing the GIL [does consider these problems](https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/#container-thread-safety), but does not give a more concrete memory model. "the GIL ensures that some operations are effectively atomic … This PEP preserves that property."

Comment: @amon Great reference, thanks for that.  Would you happen to know if there's somewhere that explains which operations are effectively atomic under the GIL (or not)?

Comment: @JimmyJames All of this is pretty implementation-defined. Any C code can be assumed to be atomic unless it explicitly releases the GIL. So individual interpreter opcodes, and most functions that have a native implementation. But all of this is well hidden from the Python code, making it impossible to reason reliably. This means mutexes for everything more interesting than maybe setting/checking a shared flag. Unlike in C, a busy wait like `while not ready: pass` should be safe.